# Form tag on master page and Content pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, master-pages

I have a ASP.NET application with one Master Page and Multiple content pages.

This is a start of Master Page

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%-- Scripts Omitted --%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
```

Now, i have a Registration page with a form to submit. Here is the start

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<br />
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div class="register">
    <br />
            .
            .
            .
```

Whenever I tried to run the `Register.aspx` page, it gives me error as : `A page can have only one server-side Form tag.` and I know its because I have a Form tag on Master Page. Now if I tried to remove the form tag from Master Page (Which I thought unnecessary), I got error as : `Control 'ctl01' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.`

My Question is : **How can I use `Form` tag on Master as well as on content page without removing `ScriptManager`. Or is there any alternative to accomplish this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the form tag from your content pages - the form tag on the master page will be sufficient.  You will need the ContentPlaceHolder tags on the master page to be within the form for this to work.

Comment: Even if i have a Form to submit ?

Comment: Yes.  The form will already be there, because it's on the master page.

Comment: So should i remove `runat=server` from controls also ?

Comment: No.  Leave everything the same, apart from removing `<form runat="server">` from your registration (and other content) pages.